# PHP Memory limit problem while creating xml of magento products

Tags: php, magento

Thanks in advance,

I need help in solving php memory problem,

I have created a script in php that automatically fetch magento product data,the problem is that when there is large number of product in database, the script gives memory fatal error i have changed the memory limit to 256M in my php.ini but still the script not executing totally.

i have checked the script its working fine if there is number of product is not too much but if there is larger number my script not working..

Please help...

-Thanks
Jitendra Dhobi

Comment: Now this is a tricky one, especially without knowing the code.

Comment: What do you need fetched data for?

Comment: i  need magentos products some fileds like category,productid,product name,images url etc..in xml and i have more than 5000 products in the database i am using magentos class for this not  database directly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento has some memory leaks in its implementation of the Product class, so this will be an issue into the future. This seems to be part of the reason that the import/export utilities in the system work in relatively small chunks.

If you are using this data on the client side, pagination is definitely the way to go. If this is some kind of data dump, you could consider grabbing the data at a lower level than the Magento objects. This approach will be faster, but much more fragile when it comes to changes between Magento versions.

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe